# Can I create Flash Loan with Pact language?

Tags: pact-lang

I'm trying to develop a flashloan with Pact. I can do this with solidity but I'm searching for a precise resource that can help me out using pact.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of resources on learning pact,

1. Tutorial series (outdated but still valuable i think) :https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4G3uLl2K-dlzQkRXeCTbfpbZUVSmRrq7 (includes basic loan examples in intermediate..)
2. Documentation pact-language.readthedocs.io/
3. Twitter...

But it's highly unlikely you'll find concrete full examples of "flash loans" the language isn't as widely used as solidity. Instead learn the basics of pact, then break down your question/problem into small steps and then ask/figure out how to achieve each in pact.